# Make button action canceled if dragged outside a certain area

Tags: java, android

I have a microphone button in my app with which user inputs voice. It is using an OnTouchListener to detect whether user holds down the button or not. If they hold the button but drag their finger outside the button, MotionEvent still considers action as "ACTION_DOWN", even if they touch near the edge of the screen, as long as they don't stop touching. We need to change that so if the user drags their finger off of the button then MotionEvent picks up as "ACTION_UP".

```
recordBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {

        //User stops touching the button.
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if(isRecording) {
                stopRecording();
                isRecording = false;
            }
            break;

        //User touches the button.
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if(!isRecording) {
                startRecording();
                isRecording = true;
            }
            break;

        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.9">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recordText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/custom_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="195dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="@string/hold_the_mic_and_record"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/custom_button"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/microphone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How about using `case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`!!

Comment: if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
  return true;
}
if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
  return true;
}
if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
  return true;
}

Comment: I used a new case for the ACTION_MOVE with the ACTION_UP so they get the same treatment from the app. The app does not record sound this way. The button activates and stops working instantly, as if it detected the slightest px touch movement and stopped. I think it has to be controlled differently, maybe it can be done with pure XML, to somehow limit the acceptable touch area of the button.